# a piece of javascript code from codepen.io doenst work on localhost, how to make it work?

Tags: javascript

```
see the code: http://codepen.io/yusufbkr/pen/myXvLw
```

I try to use this code from codepen.io in localhost. I made a folder called slider within it I have index.html.

Then i made a folder name it javascript within it i copied the js code and name it slider.js.

in index.html i wrote script src="javascript/slider.js" (i opened and closed the script correctlly)

the end result is not working, can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong and how to make it work. Im newbie in javascript. thanks alot.

Comment: Can you share the entire index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely missing JQuery. Add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To your `<head>`

[W3Schools link on getting started with JQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

Comment: try this version: `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js` Thats the exact one from the codepen

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript" src="javascript/slider.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">

  <!--slider-->
  <div class="fadeslider">
    <!--slide-->
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="text">1</div>
    </div>
    <!--#slide-->
    <!--slide-->
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="text">2</div>
    </div>
    <!--#slide-->
    <!--slide-->
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" />
      <div class="text">3</div>
    </div>
    <!--#slide-->

    <!--slide-->
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="" />
      <div class="text">4</div>
    </div>
    <!--#slide-->

    <div class="slideback"><</div>
    <div class="slidenext">></div>
    <div class="slidelist">
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--#slider-->

</div>


</body>
</html>
```